# Cassandra Sub-millisecond Latency for CAS updates

Tags: cassandra

We are trying to achieve sub millisecond latency for CAS( compare and set) updates in a simple column family on cassandra( v2.1.8) running on single node. We run a sequence of tests each comprising of one read and one write CAS operation( RW)  from a single thread on the same machine and see about 4 ms at best for them.

When we profile the Cassandra process we see the SEPWorker class spend majority of time in spin wait and the actual RW operation takes much less time. We analyzed the code and added some tracing statements around the LockSupport.parkNanos method which is used in SEPWorker.doWaitSpin method and we see that even though it is scheduled to sleep for about 12 µs on an average, it actually sleep for 800 µs per call. So, this would add on an average 400 µs to the latency due to spin wait for a single SEPWorker’s task. Note that for CAS operation, paxos requires multiple such tasks to be executed which adds this overhead multiple times.

Can anyone suggest how this overhead can be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is a general problem when it comes to scheduling thread execution. Unfortunately it's not possible to park threads in a WAITING state for an arbitrary precise time interval. What you could do is try to optimize the interrupt timer frequency for Linux. But since 800 µs is already pretty responsive, I wouldn't bet to see much performance improvements for your use case. Also Paxos as a consensus protocol isn't designed for a minimal number of round trips and this kind of micro optimizations will not help you to work around this fact.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan if my calculation is correct, the overhead of waiting seems to be quite high in comparison to actual work e.g. a read or write which takes about 50µs. So, even for non-paxos operations, it adds about 10x overhead to the latency. <br>
Is sub-ms latencies unheard of in cassandra? I couldn't find any results where people have achieved it.

Comment: You should be able to see sub-ms latency at least for CL ONE. See also the following ticket for proposed changes to concurrency handling: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10989

Comment: Thanks Stefan, for the link. Looks the scheduling overhead should get reduced when Cassandra moves out of SEDA architecture. I tried naively modifying the code to perform the work in the same netty thread and I see big improvement. Anyways, till Cassandra resolves this we will try to mitigate the latency by changing our design to minimize calls to Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a JIRA and propose a patch to the core Cassandra team

Comment: Thanks @doanduyhai I was wondering if this is by design and traded off for scalability. I can see there are plans to make things more async e.g. storageproxy etc. So, I doubt they would make tasks processing synchronous. I am wondering though if there are any recommendations for cassandra\jdk\os level settings which can improve things a bit.